# Is there any common website for Spanish intercity bus timetables?

Tags: buses, spain, online-resources

As I wrote in [an answer some time ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7527/583), there are, in my opinion, very good bus connections in Andalusia (and elsewhere in Spain). But I don't know of a single site where you could **easily** check the routes, schedules, and prices for *any* intercity bus trips in Spain.

Checking websites of individual companies is a workaround, yes. And if you don't know what company runs a certain route, you can usually google it up; for example: "[*santander bilbao autobus*](https://www.google.es/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=santander%20bilbao%20autobus)" → at least Termibus and ALSA.)

But my question is, **is there any good aggregate bus search engine for Spain**? Something like [Plataforma 10](http://www.plataforma10.com/) for Argentina & neighbouring countries, or [Matkahuolto](http://www.matkahuolto.fi/en/) for Finland.

Answer (score 5):

When I was living in Spain I always used [Movelia](http://www.movelia.es/). They also have an [english version](http://www.movelia.es/en/) now.

EDIT: Apparently [AvanzaBus](http://www.avanzabus.com/web/default.aspx) is not an aggregate of bus companies (thanks for the comment)

Comment: Thanks! For some routes this seems ok, but not for all. Apparently they only have schedules of *some* companies. One example: [Socibus](http://www.socibus.es/) runs a night bus from Cádiz to Madrid, but Movelia doesn't know about it.

Comment: I didn't know that, in fact I booked once a bus From Madrid to Cadiz (many hours trip) but it wasn't at night and I found it with Movelia. If I find a complete bus search site, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Grupo Avanza is just one bus company (albeit large one; and it's also a private operator of some bus stations in Spain). But it's *not* an aggregate of Spanish bus schedules. (Try searching e.g. for Santander - Bilbao buses, and this becomes very clear.)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you check out a Montreal Start-Up called [BusBud](http://www.busbud.com/en/) - they are handling schedules from around the world including intercity schedules in Spain.

Comment: +1, this looks promising. I tried some searches (e.g. Santander-Bilbao, Sevilla-Cádiz, Valencia-Madrid), and it found meaningful results for all. I also like the fact that you get clean permalinks to any search.

Comment: The main weakness with Busbud is that it's based on user contributions, and for many routes no-one has simply has entered anything, or the information may well be out-of-date. Bus companies have the option [verify their schedules](http://www.busbud.com/en/about/faq#faq-accuracy), but that hasn't happened with Spanish timetables (and I doubt it will anytime soon).

Comment: Have tried BusBud many times in Spain and USA.  Spain, it always tells me ALSA or no route known.  USA, I've only seen Greyhound and one other.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a site called [AAutobuses.com](http://www.aautobuses.com/).

> El portal aautobuses.com le ofrece información sobre las principales
>   líneas regulares de autobuses de nuestro país.

The site isn't very pretty, and it's only in Spanish<sup>*****</sup>.

Anyway, **AAutobuses seems reasonably comprehensive**. Compared to the other options presented, it is better:

- *If* [Movelia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9117/583) works for some route (e.g. Logroño - Bilbao), then the information provided is more complete (= includes price, etc) than that of AAutobuses. But for lots of routes Movelia is just useless.
- With [Budbus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9137/583) it just depends on whether someone has happened to enter the timetables you're looking for. AAutobuses was better or equal for everything I tried.

(Some of my test searches: Santander–Bilbao, Sevilla–Cádiz, Valencia–Madrid, Vigo–La Coruña, Logroño–Bilbao.)

---

<sup>*****</sup>That shouldn't matter much, as long as you understand what something like `LMXJV` or `LMXJVSD` means on the timetables. If you don't, here's the key:

```
L = Monday (lunes)
M = Tuesday (martes)
X = Wednesday (miércoles)
J = Thursday (jueves)
V = Friday (viernes)
S = Saturday (sábado)
D = Sunday (domingo)
```