# Basque country by bus

Tags: buses, car-rentals, basque-country

We have 2 nights in Bilbao, 1 night in Hondarribia and 1 night in Saint Jean de Luz.

We will be in this area a week before the Film Festival and I know everything will be very crowded. I thought of driving but thinking about struggling to find parking and huge parking fees has given me to consider bus.

What is the best way to do this trip round trip, leaving on the 14.09 and returning to Bilbao on 16.09? I need to be able to find the best bus connections and the times for these. Do you book round-trip tickets and get on and off on different days or point to point?

Thank you.

Comment: This Q&A https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9113/is-there-any-common-website-for-spanish-intercity-bus-timetables may help you with your search.

Comment: Have you considered the train? That often works better than the bus in that region. https://www.sncf.com/en